# Rearrange TimeSlots in FullCalendar on agendaWeek view

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to modify the timeslot on the leftmost part of the agendaWeek view of the fullcalendar changing it which starts from 7am to 1am. Notice that there's some red shaded timeslots which means CLOSED. I have looked in to the manual for reference but somethings doesnt add up. Please help. THanks ^_^

Comment: Ok, but what have you tried?

Comment: Sorry, the time on the leftmost part on agendaWeek view (which says 12am, 1am, 2am, 3am, so on) i need to arrange them like 7am, 8am, 9am....11pm, 12am, and 1am

Answer (score 0):

Use fullcalendar's `minTime` and `maxTime` fields.

Example:

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    ....
    ....
    minTime: 7,
    maxTime: 13
});
```